# Using collection_check_boxes, is it possible to define a div that would contain the labels and inputs created from it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Normally, if I use the following:

```
collection_check_boxes(:params,:tools,Tool.all, 'id', 'name') do |b|
  b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
end
```

I'd get something like this:

```
<label for="params_tool_7">
  <input id="params_tool_7" name="params[tools][]" type="checkbox" value="7" />
  Hammer
</label>
<label for="params_tool_8">
  <input id="params_tool_8" name="params[tools][]" type="checkbox" value="8" />
  Screwdriver
</label>
```

Is there any way to make it output a div encapsulating the label and input, like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="params_tool_7">
    <input id="params_tool_7" name="params[tools][]" type="checkbox" value="7" />
    Hammer
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="params_tool_8">
    <input id="params_tool_8" name="params[tools][]" type="checkbox" value="8" />
    Screwdriver
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. It works, but I think there could be a better way.

I use a table as a layout for the checkboxes, as there's 2 other "groups" of checkboxes right next to it, so each one takes a cell.

The code is something like this (HAML):

```
%table
  %tr
    %th Options #1
    %th Options #2
    %th Options #3
  %tr
    %td
      =collection_check_boxes(:params, :tools, Tool.all, :id, :name) do |b|
        .checkbox=b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
    %td
      =collection_radio_buttons(:params, :boxes, Box.all, :id, :name) do |b|
        .radio=b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
    %td
      =collection_check_boxes(:params, :colors, Color.all, :id, :name) do |b|
        .checkbox=b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
```

So, this is effectively wrapping each 'label' and 'input' with a div, which in this case they have the 'checkbox' and 'radio' classes. It works as I required it, but I'm repeating code on each one, which theoretically should be solved by a helper, but I'm not too sure how to include code in them that's not supposed to be evaluated.

Anyway, it works for now, 'til a find a more elegant solution.